# c# - Castle - No component for supporting the service - Fluent registration and resolution of Generic with generics parameters

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle

If i use one-by-one component registration everything resolves ok.. my problem is fluent registration, any thoughts?

Example

```
public class MyFilter:Filter {}

public class MyEntity:Entity {}

public class ReadCommandHandler<TEntity,TFilter> : ICommandHandler<IReadCommand<TFilter>, IEnumerable<TEntity>> where TEntity : Entity where TFilter : Filter
```

Installer

```
container.Register(Types.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>)).WithService.AllInterfaces());
```

this results in (debugger view)

ReadCommandHandler<·TEntity·, ·TFilter·> / ICommandHandler< IReadCommand<·TFilter·>, IEnumerable<·TEntity·>>

so it seems is ok .. but then if i tried this

```
var biz = container.Resolve(typeof(ICommandHandler<IReadCommand<MyFilter>,IEnumerable<MyEntity>>))
```

or this

```
var biz = container.Resolve(typeof(ICommandHandler<IReadCommand<Filter>,IEnumerable<Entity>>))
```

the result is "No component for supporting the service"

whats the matter with this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay .. as one possible approach i "resolved" this with IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy

Setup and resolve:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(
        Types.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(ReadCommandHandler<,>)).BasedOn(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>))
        .If(p => !p.IsInterface)
        .WithServiceBase()
.Configure(
            c => c.ExtendedProperties(
                Property.ForKey(Castle.Core.Internal.Constants.GenericImplementationMatchingStrategy)
                    .Eq(new GenericImplementationMatchingStrategy()))));




var biz = container.Resolve(typeof(ICommandHandler<IReadCommand<MyFilter>, IEnumerable<MyEntity>>));
```

GenericStrategyImplementation

```
public class GenericImplementationMatchingStrategy : IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type[]> dicStrategyCommandHandler = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type[]>();
    public Type[] GetGenericArguments(ComponentModel model, CreationContext context)
    {
        return dicStrategyCommandHandler.GetOrAdd(context.RequestedType.FullName, (key) =>
            {

                if (context.RequestedType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICommandHandler<,>))
                {
                    var service = model.Implementation.GetInterfaces().Where(p => { return p.Name == context.RequestedType.Name; }).FirstOrDefault(); //  model.Implementation.GetInterfaces()[0];
                    if (service != null)
                    {
                        List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
                        foreach (var item in model.Implementation.GetGenericArguments())
                        {
                            var name = item.Name;
                            var type = serviceGetType(name, service, context.RequestedType);
                            types.Add(type);

                        }
                        return types.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
            );
    }

    private Type serviceGetType(string name, Type service, Type requestedType)
    {
        var args = service.GetGenericArguments().ToArray();
        var argsRequested = requestedType.GetGenericArguments().ToArray();
        for (int i=0;i<args.Count();i++ )
        {
            Type itemDecla = args[i];
            Type itemRequested = argsRequested[i];
            if (itemDecla.Name == name)
                return itemRequested;
            else
            {
                var recur = serviceGetType(name, itemDecla, itemRequested);
                if (recur != null) return recur;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What do you think .. something better?

My only nice-to-know question is, why if my component lifestyle is singleton, the resolve method calls GenericImplementationMatchingStrategy each time i call Resolve(..).